# Automatic inclusion of newly created SharePoint site in existing retention policy

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, retention, compliance-center

Is there any way to include newly created SharePoint site in an existing retention policy created in security and compliance?

or once in a month all newly created sites to be added in a current retention policy?

We do not want to add all the sites in retention policy and only want to add sites which are created by a specific user. Is this possible through any out of the box functionality? If not what could be other potential ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically add new sites explicitly to the retention policies out-of-the-box.

One way to automate it is to script this with PowerShell. I'm including all PowerShell commands you'll need to complete this task.

**Get a list of SharePoint Online sites**

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
```

**Install the Exchange Online PowerShell Module**

```
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser
```

**Establish a new session**

```
Connect-PPSSession
```

**[Get existing retention policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-retentioncompliancepolicy?view=exchange-ps)**

```
Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy -Identity "SharePoint Retention Polocy" -DistributionDetail
```

**Add a new site to the retention policy**

```
Set-RetentionCompliancePolicy -Identity "SharePoint Retention Polocy" -AddSharePointLocation "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/finance"
```